# How to handle Array of objects in Vuex, WHen we have Complex form structure

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I need some suggestion in handling complex form object in vueX,

I have this data set in my vuex store

```
{
    "sync_block": false,
    "site_name": "",
    "meter_heading": "",
    "external_rff": "",
    "account": [{
        "personal": [{
            "contacts": [{
                "con_title": "",
                "con_fName": "",
                "con_lName": "",
                "con_job_title": "",
                "dob": "",
                "checked": false,
                "is_selected": true,
                "nest_uid": ""
            }],
            "is_selected": true,
            "nest_uid": "",
            "checked": false
        }]
    }]
```

What's the best way to handle this nested Object, Arrays in the component ?
for now I am doing very ugly code like this.

```
 [MutationTypes.MUTATE_FORMDATA_CONTACTS](state, payload) {

          .state
            .form
            .account[index]
            .personal[index1]
            .contacts[index2] = payload.value

        },
```

And I am committing something like this

```
let data = {
              "con_title": "Titel",
              "con_fName": "Name",
              "con_lName": "l name",
              "con_job_title": "",
              "dob": "20-04-1990",
              "checked": false,
              "is_selected": true,
              "nest_uid": ""
            }
this.$store.commit('MUTATE_FORMDATA_CONTACTS', { index: 0, index1: 0, index2: 0, key: 'data', 'value': data })
```

Can someone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 0):

you could utilize [lodash#set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set)

```
// component
this.$store.commit('MUTATE_FORMDATA_CONTACTS', {
  path: 'account[0].personal[0].contacts[0]',
  value: data 
})

// while utilizing lodash#set in the store
// import {set} from 'lodash-es'

[MutationTypes.MUTATE_FORMDATA_CONTACTS](state, payload) {
  set(state.form,payload.path,payload.data);
},
```